# Вывести отфильтрованый список с помощью vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть такой небольшой проект: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-curran-djn1l?file=/src/views/Home.vue)

Список из постов и select фильтр.

**Home.vue:**

```
<b-form-select v-model="selected" :options="options"></b-form-select>

<ul v-for="post in getPostsFilter" :key="post.id">
  <li>
    {{ post.id }}
    {{ post.completed }}

     <b-form-checkbox v-model="post.completed">
        I accept the terms and use
     </b-form-checkbox>

    {{ post.title }}
  </li>
</ul>


import { mapActions, mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    DefaultLayout,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selected: this.$store.state.selected,
      options: [
        {
          value: "all",
          text: "All",
        },
        {
          value: "completed",
          text: "Completed",
        },
        {
          value: "not_completed",
          text: "Not completed",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["getPostsFilter"]),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["fetchPosts"]),
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchPosts();
  },
};
</script>
```

*store.js:*

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    posts: [],
    selected: "all"
  },
  getters: {
    getPosts(state) {
      return state.posts;
    },
    getPostsFilter(state) {
      if (state.selected === "all") {
        return state.posts;
      }

      if (state.selected === "completed") {
        return state.posts.filter((p) => (p = p.completed));
      }

      if (state.selected === "not_completed") {
        return state.posts.filter((p) => (p = !p.completed));
      }
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setPosts(state, payload) {
      state.posts = payload;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async fetchPosts({ commit, dispatch }) {
      axios
        .get(" https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/?_limit=3")
        .then((response) => {
          this.commit("setPosts", response.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  }
});
```

**Вопрос:** Как отображать отфильтрованый список при выборе в select completed\not_completed\all ?

Comment: В Вашей реализации надо: 1) сделать мутацию, которая бы изменяла  selected 2) повесить watch на selected, который в компоненте. Желательно сделать через другую переменную. При срабатывания   watch, вызывать мутацию изменяющую selected

Comment: Другой вариант, передать selected в getpostfilter.  https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/getters.html#%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поправил ваш код.

Без объяснений сразу готовый рабочий вариант: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-golick-ntikv?file=/src/views/Home.vue)

**`Store.js`**.
Добавил в `мутации` и `actions` метод который изменяет `status` в объекте `filter`

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    posts: [],
    filter: {
      status: "all"
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getPosts(state) {
      return state.posts;
    },
    getPostsFilter(state) {
      const { posts, filter } = state;

      if (filter.status === "all") return posts;

      if (filter.status === "completed")
        return posts.filter((post) => !!post.completed);

      if (filter.status === "not_completed")
        return posts.filter((post) => !post.completed);
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setPosts(state, payload) {
      state.posts = payload;
    },
    setFilterStatus(state, status) {
      state.filter.status = status;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async fetchPosts({ commit }) {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(
          " https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/?_limit=10"
        );
        commit("setPosts", data);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    },
    setFilterStatus({ commit }, status) {
      commit("setFilterStatus", status);
    }
  }
});
```

---

**`Home.vue`**. Добавил в `mapActions` метод изменяющий статус, добавил `watch` который при изменении будет стучать на добавленный `action`.

```
export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    DefaultLayout,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selected: this.$store.state.selected,
      options: [
        {
          value: "all",
          text: "All",
        },
        {
          value: "completed",
          text: "Completed",
        },
        {
          value: "not_completed",
          text: "Not completed",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["getPostsFilter"]),
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["fetchPosts", 'setFilterStatus']),
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchPosts();
  },
  watch: {
    selected(value) {
      this.setFilterStatus(value);
    } 
  }
};
```

Comment: Actions setFilterStatus лишний. Можно сразу делать commit

Comment: @Дмытрык  https://hsto.org/webt/fu/pn/0e/fupn0eoshovoxxz1csrbzl67hoy.png

Comment: Спасибо, т.е. status не изменяю, а что-то от него хочу! Спасибо!

Comment: Эта схема при работе с сервером. Для асинхронных операций. Если операции синхронно, то вызывать мутации можно напрямую. А так, actions, это лишний слой

Comment: @Дмытрык я из тех, кто решает задачу так, как описано в документации, но с ваших уст все куда логичнее, `Actions` нужны исключительно для асинхронщины, `Mutations` должны быть синхронны. В данном контексте это действительно лишний слой и он по-сути дублирует `Mutations` и все.